# Handle backslash in the connection string

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a following connection string in app.config

```
<add name="myDBConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=ASDFG\SQLEXPRESS;
         Initial Catalog=ZAQ;
         Integrated Security=True;"/>
```

in my C# code then, when I get this string DB is always evaluated as `"ASDFG\\SQLEXPRESS"`

I couldn't put @ since app.config doesn't like it. Also, if I say

```
ASDFG\\SQLEXPRESS
```

it gets evaluated as

```
ASDFG\\\\SQLEXPRESS
```

and not open the connection.

Thank You,

Comment: I've never had this problem.  How are you retrieving and using the connection string?  There is no concept of escaping with `"\"` in `app.config` configuration settings.

Comment: Isn't `ASDFG\SQLEXPRESS` what you want? Can't understand the `in my C# code then, when I get this string DB is always evaluated as "ASDFG\SQLEXPRESS"` line

Comment: "ASDFG\SQLEXPRESS" looks correct.  Do you have a type-o in your question?

Comment: @manojlds, @WEFX: I fixed OP's post.  Apparently SO editor turns `"\\"` into `"\"` when written as text in double-quotes.  lol, how ironic.

Comment: var connectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

Comment: @socialMatrix: So what is the error message you are getting when trying to connect?

Comment: Is there an actual problem here? Like, can you connect to the database or not? If not, do you get an exception?

Comment: Hi everyone, this is crazy, but I was using SQLite command to connect to SQL server DB :-( ... thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The debugger may display it as `ASDFG\\SQLEXPRESS`, but it's just escaping that backslash for display purposes.

Comment: Hi, this is crazy, but I was using SQLite command to connect to SQL server DB :-( ... thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

use this in codebehind

```
string conString =
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["myDBConnectionString"].ToString();
```

Comment: Hi, this is crazy, but I was using SQLite command to connect to SQL server DB :-( ... thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> always evaluated as "ASDFG\SQLEXPRESS"

Which is quite correct. Any actual problems opening the Db?

Comment: this is crazy, but I was using SQLite command to connect to SQL server DB :-( ... thanks a lot for your help.