# Excel VBA - connection string to SQL Server 2008

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 from Excel VBA using the connection string (`ADODB.Connection`).

```
"Driver={SQL Native Client};Data Source=" & Range("Svr").Value & ";Database=" & Range("DB").Value & ";Trusted_Connection=yes"
```

When I try to open the connection I get this error

> *Error (-2147467259) Description - [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name too long*

Can some one please provide me a sample

Comment: Are `Svr` and `DB` named ranges in your workbook?

Comment: @Widor...Yes they are in my workbook

Comment: Can you show us a bit more of the code? Maybe your connection string isn't the problem. It [looks like you haven't instantiated the object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163475) you are using to make your connection.

Comment: @JMK .....Yes you are right.....I Misspelled the obj name, but after that when i try to open the connection i get the below error "Error (-2147467259) Description - [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long "

Comment: Are there any special characters in your data source name? Or is it really long?

Comment: here is my Server name - "xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx.xx.xxxxxxxx.xxx\xxxx01xxx" , where x is a alphabet

Comment: Instead of Data Source=, have you tried `"SERVER=" & Server & ";"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the backslash in your connection string is causing your issues, try and escape it like so:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx.xx.xxxxxxxx.xxx\\xxxx01xxx
```

Also, putting quotes around each value wouldn't hurt:

```
"Driver={SQL Native Client};Data Source='" & Range("Svr").Value & "';Database='" & Range("DB").Value & "';Trusted_Connection=yes"
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998110/969613).