# unrecognized escape character string r

Tags: sql-server, r

I am trying to establihs connection with database server using

```
library(RODBC)
myconn <- odbvConnect(dsn="SERVER\NAME", uid="user", pwd="password")
```

Server name has "\". I've also tryed using

```
"SERVER\\NAME"
```

as suggested on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695879/error-r-is-an-unrecognized-escape-in-character-string-starting-c-r) topic. But that doesn't work either because than boath slashes are written in and I get error that server couldn't be found.

So question: how do I need to type \ so R will understand it as single character?

Comment: "both slashes are written" only when `print()`ing inside of R because it doesn't escape values. If you `cat()` that value in R you should see a single slash. So the string "SERVER\\NAME" in R has just one slash. What is the problem you are having with your connection?

Answer (score 0):

```
myconn <- odbvConnect(dsn=@"SERVER\NAME", uid="user", pwd="password")
```

Comment: I get: Error: unexpected '@' in "myconn <- odbvConnect(dsn=@"

Comment: This article could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998058/handle-backslash-in-the-connection-string

Answer (score 0):

```
cn<-odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
server=LPT-11\\SQLEXPRESS;database=dbname;Uid=username;
Pwd=pass;trusted_connection=yes;")
```